# Replacing text in XML ignoring bold and italic tags

Tags: python, xml, regex, xml-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

I have an an arbitrary XML string, that also has `<b>, <i>` tags that have the usual meaning.
I need to perform string replacement in the plain text only. Nothing in the node definitions should be replaced.

For example, I want to replace "hello" with a *.
XML like `<hello a="hello">text sayh<b>ell</b>o more text</hello>` should become `<hello a="hello">text say* more text</hello>`

What is the best way to do this?
I was going to use `regex` only, but the question was voted down.

Comment: Regular expressions should never be used for parsing XML. You really need some sort of recursive parser for that, and regular expressions are not recursive. Just use a real XML parser.

Comment: Why not resort to DOM parsing?

Comment: What sort of multi-GiB XML files do you have there that DOM parsing is too slow?

Comment: @Jan, Joey and Kevin: because it's presumably slower, I need something super-fast: i have complex patterns, with 100s of them ORed like this `pattern1|pattern2|pattern3....|pattern100`

Comment: @mercador regexes are not sufficient to parse _arbitrary_ XML at any speed. Even for known XML, it's still a hack.

Comment: Note that regexes can be arbitrarily slow, while XML parsers are linear since XML is LL1.

Comment: Text nodes in XML can still contain arbitrarily large chunks of HTML. Here's why: `<![CDATA[`

Comment: In my XML, there is no CDATA. I will edit the question.

Comment: What about `hello<outer>hello<inner>hello</inner>hello</outer>hello`? What should that look like after replacing?

Comment: @TimPietzcker : it should look like `*<outer>*<inner>*</inner>*</outer>*` althought it's not a valid xml

Comment: It's 2013. Use an XML parser.

Comment: @JackManey: my XML is not necessarily valid, it's user-generated... So a parser may throw an error.

Comment: @mercador - That's what `try`/`catch` blocks are for.

Comment: @mercador: If your XML is not necessarily valid, it is even more of a reason to use XML parser.

Comment: How big are your xml files, and how complicated the replacements? Please give a real world example.

Comment: There is no usual meaning of <i> and <b> in XML.

Answer (score 0):

A very quick and dirty (emphasis on dirty) solution that simply implements the rule "Match only if the next angle bracket is not a closing angle bracket" would be

```
hello(?![^<>]*>)
```

This might work on your XML file, but it can fail on valid XML in various ways (and on invalid XML even more).

**Edit:**

Since my original answer, the question has changed substantially, so the answer is no longer correct. If you want to ignore bold/italic tags, you either first have to remove them entirely, searching for `</?[bi]>` and replacing all that with the empty string, then run the above regex (but that will remove *all*  these tags, not just the ones inside `hello`, or use

```
</?[bi]>h</?[bi]>e</?[bi]>l</?[bi]>l</?[bi]>o</?[bi]>(?![^<>]*>)
```

instead of the above regex. By now I think you can see that regular expressions are not a reliable tool for this kind of task. But that should already have been clear from the comments.